# Looking for a movie about a group of people in abandoned city

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I watched it in 2010. It's in English. Possibly Hollywood movie.

**Plot**

A group of people exploring an abandoned city. They're looking for a person. While exploring the city, they encounter many of strange creature. I remember they fight a ape-like creature, giant aquatic snake, giant bat, dino-like creature and many more. There are also man eater plants.

The group searching from building to building. The protagonist meet a botanist and talking about the whereabout of the person they're looking for.

Comment: Why people keep asking about this movie http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=A+Sound+of+Thunder+[identify-this-movie]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A Sound of Thunder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0318081/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Detailed plot [on Wikipedia here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder_(film))

> "**Ryer and Rand lead a group through the city - now filled with evolved
>   and deadly Baboonlizards and other new hazards that kill some of their
>   party members - to find Eckels and Middleton.** Eckels is safe but
>   asserts he remained on the path, while Middeleton, **poisoned by the new
>   wildlife**, takes his life before they can stop him. However, they are
>   able to find a dead butterfly on the sole of the suit he used for the
>   safari. The party make it back to Time Safari after more time waves
>   hit, now finding the time machine partially underwater and unusable.
>   Rand obtains the hard drive containing the TAMI software with plans to
>   use it with the nearby university's particle accelerator as a
>   substitute time machine.
>
> Ryer and Rand are the only two survivors once they finally make it to
>   the university, Rand noting that the appearance of **simian-like
>   Babboonlizards** from the latest time wave means the next one will wipe
>   away humanity. Rand prepares the accelerator and stays behind while
>   Ryer goes through the time portal, just as the last time wave hits
>   turning Rand into **a humanoid catfish-like creature**. Ryer catches up to
>   the previous expedition, catches Middleton to prevent him stepping on
>   the butterfly, tells Jenny the bio-filter is off at the same time
>   asking her to give his earlier self a recording of the events he has
>   witnessed. The expedition returns without incident to the future they
>   had left. Ryer shares the footage with Rand."

Here is a collection of the various creatures in the movie:

In the clip above, at 2:58 **fight with the ape-like creature** (baboonlizard), at 6:13 the **giant aquatic snake**, at 4:57 **the giant bats**, etc.

Ape-like creature (baboonlizard):

[image]

Aquatic snake:

[image]

Giant bat:

[image]

Dino:

[image]